# Possible to run msbuild in Jenkins on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

I am learning Jenkins and today I installed Jenkins on an Ubuntu 13.10 AWS instance. Everything overall has been going well, except I have not had any luck building using msbuild.  Jenkins installed the MSBuild plugin fine, but I keep getting errors when it tries to build.

I have been scouring google and have been having a heck of a time finding anything showing this working on ubuntu.  So I thought I would post here and get a final answer. My projects are in VS and I am pointing the msbuild call to the sln.  Any help would be great! Thanks!

Dan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The msbuild plugin is just a wrapper to call the msbuild executable. Since java is portable, the plugin will install on Ubuntu. Run? Unlikely.

A (probably not) possible way to get a MSbuild to run on a Linux server is to use xbuild out of the mono project. You could also try Wine.

You can also spend hours upon hours trying to make wine from oranges.

Your better option is to install Jenkins on a Microsoft OS based cloud server.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71bcb26b-3149-41c7-9ad7-fe908ffe983e/msbuild-on-linux?forum=msbuild

Comment: Installing to Windows Server 2012 was the option I went with.  Thanks so much for the reply.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: voted up for "...You can also spend hours upon hours trying to make wine from oranges..."

Comment: Small info: If WPF is used, you can't use xbuild from Mono. Mono will not support WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have faced the same problem with that. But if you just want to build your project and then replace the build version on to somewhere else then you can go ahead and temporarily install ".net"(in jenkins workspace) using this command.

```
wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/022d9abf-35f0-4fd5-8d1c-86056df76e89/477f1ebb70f314054129a9f51e9ec8ec/dotnet-sdk-2.2.207-linux-x64.tar.gz
mkdir -p $HOME/dotnet && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-2.2.207-linux-x64.tar.gz -C $HOME/dotnet
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
#command to built (edit as per your project)
dotnet publish -c Release /p:RuntimeFrameworkVersion=2.2.0
```